# The dependent tool 'svcutil.exe' is not found

Tags: wcf

I compile a new WCF application and upon running gave the error

> "The dependent tool 'svcutil.exe' is
>   not found. "

Could any one tell me what to do??

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem install the Windows SDK .Net 3.5 Here the [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC&displaylang=en) to download it from.  Install that and the WCF Test Client should run without error.

Comment: Windows SDK .net 3.5 i already installed on my system.After some attempts i resolved the error.thanks for your reply

Comment: I copied and pasted 'svcutil.exe' at path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin.Now its running fine.I suppose that 'svcutil.exe' was erased from machine while installing higher versions of framework.